# jquery ajax data is not printing in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-2

my problem is when i try to show a value by ajax calling,it shows the value to "generic" class but when i try to show it on the parent row it is not showing anything.
here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/medical/index.php/purchase/test',
    data: 'data=' + pid,
    success: function() {
        $.get('http://localhost/medical/index.php/purchase/test', function(data) {
            $(this).parents('tr').find('.generic').html(data); // doesn't show the value
            $( ".generic" ).html(); // this show the value but in all table row
    });
}});
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is called scope. `this` in context of the anonymous function means something else than it means outside. You can do it like this

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
        $.get(..., function(data) {
            $(that).parents('tr').find('.generic').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @RahatIslamKhan You're welcome. To explain a bit more: (Basically) everytime you write `function(){` in JavaScript, `this` gets assigned something new (within this scope).